# Trouble uploading txt file into SQL from Java

Tags: java, sql, file-upload

I know I'm probably missing something really obvious but I'm having trouble with a text file uplopad into an MSSQL server from a Java app running on a windows client.  It's taking the multiple lines and loading them all into one record intead of generating a new record for each line.

The text file is generated by the java app using the System.lineSeparator() to seperate the lines and the output displays fine inspecting the file in notepad and the code to upload the txt file as below

```
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con1.prepareStatement("insert into " + 
                tableName + "(" + columnName + ") values (?)");
        pstmt.setAsciiStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        fis.close();
```

I've tried subing the System.lineSeparator() for \r\n but had no luck their either... any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: @Naren, no exceptions are thrown either by JAVA or the SQL server.  The SQL field is a VARCHAR(MAX) so I just wind up with one massive record

Answer (score 0):

Code with commentary:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

a) OK. Got the streamn representing the file

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con1.prepareStatement("insert into " + 
                tableName + "(" + columnName + ") values (?)");
```

b) OK. Got an update statement where the parameter is the value that gets put into colyumnName

```
pstmt.setAsciiStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());
```

c) This is setting the value of the parameter to the whole file stream from position 1 to the end

```
pstmt.executeUpdate();
fis.close();
```

Execute the statement and close the filestream.

You execute a SQL statement once, telling it to write the whole of the file. And this is what it's doing.

How to fix this? After step b), read the filestream line by line and for each line set the parameter value and execute the SQL statement. Or after b) read the whole filestream into a string, split it into an array of lines and for each line, set the parameter and execute the SQL.

Comment: The data set size I'm going to be working with is going to be quite large (several 10's of millions of records), so I was hoping to avoid line by line processing.  I hadn't considered splitting it into a string array, so will have a look if that might work for me this afternoon.